# A string is suddenly losing its value inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have code which should read the filenames from a file, open those, and do some calculations. Those files contain columns of data. I have declared arrays to read in the data. The strings containing file names are behaving in an erratic manner when I initialise the arrays before reading in. If the initialisation is removed, the problem is solved.

The erratic behaviour is: the string declared first isn't remaining in the memory. In the code, if I declare `d[90]` first, then a print statement at a later time does not print the previously saved value. What could be the cause?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{

  FILE *data,*model,*filenames;

  int i,imax,j,k,l;
  float fd[1000],fm[1000],td[1000],tm[1000];
  float a;
  char d[90],m[90];


  k=1;
  l=0;

  filenames=fopen("filenames.dat","r");


  while(fscanf(filenames,"%s %s",d,m)!=EOF)
   {
printf("model: %s\ndata: %s\n",m,d);

    for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
      {
        fd[i]=0;
        fm[i]=0;
        td[i]=0;
        tm[i]=0;
      }


printf("datafile name: %s\n",d);
printf("modelfile name: %s\n",m);

    data=fopen(d,"r");

    for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
      if(fscanf(data,"%f %f %f %f",&td[i],&fd[i],&a,&a)!=EOF)
        k++;
      else
        break;

    fclose(data);

printf("modelfile name: %s\n",m);
    model=fopen(m,"r");

    for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
      if(fscanf(model,"%f %f %f %f %f %f",&tm[i],&fm[i],&a,&a,&a,&a)!=EOF)
       l++;
      else
        break;

    fclose(model);


   }

}
```

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: That isn't helping. The problem persists.

Comment: That was just a comment, not an answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

In your code, with a definition like `float fd[1000]` and so on, using the `for` loop like

```
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
      {
        fd[i]=0;
        fm[i]=0;
        td[i]=0;
        tm[i]=0;
      }
```

creates [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and hence cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as essentially, you're trying to access past the allocated memory.

As `C` uses `0`-based indexing, you should be using index from `0` to `(size-1)` for an array with `size` elements.

Also, always check the return value of [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) against `NULL` to ensure it's success. In case `fopen()` failed, using the returned pointer will again invoke UB.

Comment: @Sup Please see my updated answer. And to answer the later part. Once a program shows UB, it's behaviour can be completely erratic. nothing can be guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you @Sourav Ghosh!

Comment: I would call it good practice to define the size and use it in the loop `for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)`